# SharePoint default alternate access mapping

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping

I've configured my first SharePoint 2010 server. i am new to SharePoint and my problem is alternate access mapping. Currently default address is sp2010 (server name). I've added http://sp.test.com for intranet and http://test.com for internet access. I'm confused with default address. what should be default address for SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Default zone will have the internal address of the site on which the web application is created.In your case `http://sp2010` is the default address and there is no need for you to change it.